# Strange behaviour of assert_called_with

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I am dealing with a strange behaviour of assert_called_with. My mock works, but if I try to compare the arguments which the function was called I got the error (bellow):

```
data = {"result": {"fizz": "buzz"}}
mock = MagicMock()
mock.configure_mock(**{"post.return_value": mock, "json.return_value": data})

dispatcher.session = mock

@dispatcher.dispatch()
def test():
    pass

test() # here calls self.session.post(...).json()

assert mock.post.assert_called_with()
```

Without parameters:

```
assert mock.post.assert_called_with()
```

I got the error (as expected):

```
>       assert mock.post.assert_called_with()
E       AssertionError: expected call not found.
E       Expected: post()
E       Actual: post('', json={'id': 0, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'test', 'params': {}})
E       
E       pytest introspection follows:
E       
E       Args:
E       assert ('',) == ()
E         Left contains one more item: ''
E         Full diff:
E         - ()
E         + ('',)
E       Kwargs:
E       assert {'json': {'id...'params': {}}} == {}
E         Left contains 1 more item:
E         {'json': {'id': 0, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'test', 'params': {}}}
E         Full diff:
E         - {}
E         + {'json': {'id': 0, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'test', 'params': {}}}
```

However if I pass the called arguments, like this:

```
assert mock.post.assert_called_with(
    "", json={"id": 0, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "test", "params": {}}
)
```

I got

```
>       assert mock.post.assert_called_with(
            "", json={"id": 0, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "test", "params": {}}
        )
E       AssertionError: assert None
E        +  where None = <bound method wrap_assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='mock.post' id='140014005058048'>>('', json={'id': 0, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'test', 'params': {}})
E        +    where <bound method wrap_assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='mock.post' id='140014005058048'>> = <MagicMock name='mock.post' id='140014005058048'>.assert_called_with
E        +      where <MagicMock name='mock.post' id='140014005058048'> = <MagicMock id='140014005036992'>.post
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the leading `assert` call. It should just be `mock.post.assert_called_with()`. It fails because there is an `assert` preceding that assertion on the mock object. Since `mock.post.assert_called_with()` returns `None` your test fails because it evaluates to `assert None`. You can see more in the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with).